# Why are normal bundles always locally trivial?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

Is there a quick and dirty proof that normal bundles (say of some submanifold in a smooth manifold) are always locally trivial?

My notes seem to have swept this assumption under the rug. Even pointing me to a source would be fine.

Comment: But every bundle is locally-trivial.

Comment: If you meant that the normal bundle of a submanifold is trivial, then this follows from the submanifold property, i.e., you can always find a tubular 'hood of the submanifold.

Comment: @DBFdalwayse, well, that depends on conventions. And i would say that it is quite not universally accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the answer to deal with Marie's objections in the comments.

---

Let $M$ be an $m$-manifold and $i: N \to M$ an immersed $n$-submanifold. Let us prove local triviality of the normal bundle at a point $x \in N$.

By the implicit function theorem, co-ordinate charts $U$ around $x$ and $V$ around $i(x)$ exist so that the embedding looks like the mapping $(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n) \mapsto (x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n, 0, 0, \ldots)$ from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$, where the image of the mapping has the last $m-n$ co-ordinates to be $0$.

Look at what is happening at $U$. Let $T_M(U)$ be the pullback of the tangent bundle of $M$ to $U$, and similarly for $T_N(U)$. The normal bundle $B$ on $U$ is the quotient bundle $T(M)/T(N)$. As seen by the nature of embedding which is explicitly given by the vanishing of the last few co-ordinates, this quotient is also a trivial bundle.

So the normal bundle is locally trivial. Note the use of the implicit function theorem.

Comment: "Suppose you have a trivial bundle and a trivial subbundle. Its complement is also a trivial bundle." This is false. For instance, the normal bundle of the sphere is trivial, and so is the restriction of the tangent bundle of $\mathbf R^3$ to the sphere. But the tangent bundle of the sphere is not trivial.

Comment: Also, "the" complement doesn't make sense, unless you have a Riemannian structure. Otherwise you can only speak of "a" complement.

Comment: @Marie: Edited. I hope now everything is ok.